# Wordpress site stopped working after upgrade from Google Cloud's free tier

Tags: php, wordpress, web, google-cloud-platform

I was running a Wordpress(not Bitnami) site on Google cloud’s free tier, it expired a few days ago. I upgraded today and restarted the VM. When I tried to go to the installation using the IP address, it won’t work. Anyone know why this is happening? Upon doing curl -i http://NEW_IP, I get the response "curl: (7) Failed to connect to XX.XXX.X.XXX port 80: Connection refused"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your account was suspended (expired), the VM instances were stopped. When you restarted the instances you received new (different) IP addresses. You will need to look up the new IP address assigned to your VM instance in the Google Cloud Console.

Consider changing the IP address to static from ephemeral so that it does not change in the future.

You will need to update the DNS resource records at your DNS server (if you are using domain names).

Comment: Thanks! But I was hoping that the Wordpress site would run on the new IP address provided on the GC dashboard, but I get a "This site can’t be reached" response. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Which IP address are you trying to use - the old IP address or the new one? How was the `wp-config.php` setup - IP address or domain name? Execute this command `curl -i http://REPLACE_WITH_NEW_IP_ADDRESS`. Post the output in your question.